# Why does my dog poop on 'higher ground'?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training, psychology

I have a mini micro toy poodle and each and everytime he has to poop he does so on grass that is taller than the rest or against a tree. When he does it against a tree he puts his 2 back legs as high as he possibly can against the tree and then poops.

Why does my dog poop on 'higher ground'?

Comment: He wants his poop to survive the impending flood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an animal behavior problem related to either dominance or insecurity (by the sounds of it). There may be another dog that he is trying to assert dominance over or he is insecure with his height and is trying to trick other dogs into thinking he is taller than what he is or maybe even "trick himself into thinking he is taller".

If this is causing a problem in any way, I would talk to your vet, or an animal psychologist if one is nearby.

Comment: Mm sounds about right. He is trying to be dominant over dogs he in no way is dominant over. Could be related to that he had a labrador who has helped raise him who died recently. In the last year of the labrador he was dominant over him, because the labrador was too tired/sick to do anything about it. Now he lives alone and I don't think he knows how to handle situations like meeting larger dogs than him very well. He growls at them a bit, but with slightly larger or the same size dogs there is no problem. He might have been really dependant on the labrador.